# CSS Variables on Mobile?

Tags: css

Building out a free-lance project where the client wants to be able to tweak colors easily, so I'm using CSS variables as such:

```
:root {
  --custom-1: #blah;
}

.class {
  color: var(--custom-1)
}
```

This seems to work fine on chrome and safari on my computer, but does not seem to work on mobile safari. I've tried:

```
-webkit-var-bg-red: red;

color: -webkit-var(bg-red)
```

I found that in http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/css-variables/ which I guess is outdated, because just var-bg-red wouldn't work on chrome.

Timeframe is tight, so I'd like to avoid using preprocessors. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If youre looking for a use of variables cross browsers today 2016 on your style, check [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) instead of CSS

Comment: See browser support at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility) or [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)

Comment: According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) Safari Mobile apparently (I haven't checked by testing) now supports CSS Custom Properties from v9.1. Only significant browser that doesn't is IE, but Edge does.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*#Browser_compatibility) it is compatible with mobile safari.
Are you sure you have the last version of the browser on your phone?